# Testing abstract php-class static methods that need extending classes to be meaningful

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a situation where I can't see how to properly test it.

Let's assume following structure:

- *MyAbstractBaseClass* which has a static method *getConstants* that returns all const-fields while
  *MyAbstractBaseClass* doesn't have any such fields.
- *MyExtendingClass* which extends *MyAbstractBaseClass*

Now I want to test *getConstants* without using a concrete extension of the base class.
I have seen that it is possible to get mocks for abstract-class implementations but I haven't found the possibility to add fields to the mock which would be kinda necessary to make a test that is meaningful and at the same time doesn't rely on a concrete extension.

So my question: how can I achieve that?

Comment: "MyAbstractBaseClass which has a static method getConstants that returns all const-fields while MyAbstractBaseClass doesn't have any such fields" <- sorry what? :) Anyway, this would probably fit better on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, esp if you add some code samples, which would help quite a bit.

Comment: Sorry -.-

But jeah...fortunately I already have my answer. Thanks for the hint to softwareengineering-stackexchange!

Comment: @Jeto when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat That's what I was implying (or at least attempting to imply) by "fit better" (as in "it should be there *instead of* here"). But I'll consider mentioning cross-posting explicitly next time, guess that can't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous classes are working very well for those kind of tests:

```
final class MyAbstractBaseClassTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_should_return_all_constants()
    {
        $subject = new class extends MyAbstractBaseClass {
            const SOME_CONSTANT = 'SOME VALUE';
            const ANOTHER_CONSTANT = 'ANOTHER VALUE';
        };

        self::assertEqualsCanonicalizing(['SOME_CONSTANT', 'ANOTHER_CONSTANT'], $subject::getConstants());
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function it_should_return_an_empty_list_when_there_are_no_constants()
    {
        $subject = new class extends MyAbstractBaseClass {};

        self::assertEquals([], $subject::getConstants());
    }
}
```

Comment: There we see that I am fairly new at php. It can do anonymous classes :D Didn't even think of that. Thanks a lot!